# convert utc time to cst time

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat

I have a string ("2021-11-05T22:33:10Z") which represents UTC time. I need to get the equivalent cst time("2021-11-05T16:33:10Z"). i have the below code but it returns time as
2021-11-05T17:33:10Z. Why is an hour getting add to the final time?

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
      String busDate = "2021-11-05T22:33:10Z";
      SimpleDateFormat currentFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
      currentFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
      Date utcTime = currentFormat.parse(busDate);
      
      System.out.println(utcTime); //Fri Nov 05 22:33:10 GMT 2021
      
      SimpleDateFormat updateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
      updateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
      String formattedDateTime = updateFormat.format(utcTime);
      System.out.println(formattedDateTime); //2021-11-05T17:33:10Z
   
    }
}
```

Comment: Those times are not equivalent.  The `Z` means UTC, so your second time string is six hours earlier than the first one.

Comment: Don't use `Date`, use the `java.time` classes.

Comment: [Central Daylight Time did not end until Sunday, November 7, 2021](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/chicago) in America/Chicago time zone.

Comment: Don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `TimeZone`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Use `ZonedDateTime`, `ZoneId` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

You asked:

> Why is an hour getting add to the final time?

Your expectation is incorrect. DST was in effect on the 5th in that zone.

2021-11-05T22:33:10Z = 2021-11-05T17:33:10-05:00[America/Chicago]

## Use only *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### Moment in UTC

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2021-11-05T22:33:10Z" ) ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2021-11-05T22:33:10Z

### Adjust from UTC to a time zone

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2021-11-05T17:33:10-05:00[America/Chicago]

Note that your expectation of `2021-11-05T16:33:10Z` as result is incorrect. **Chicago time was *five hours* behind UTC on November 5**, under Daylight Saving Time (DST), not six hours. DST ended on November 7, 2021. For the rest of November, Chicago time is six hours behind UTC.

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/5M8jIr).

## Real time zone names

There is no such time zone as `cst` or `CST`. To some people that means Central Standard Time, to many more people that means China Standard Time. Use these 2-4 letter pseudo-zones only for localizing in presentation to the user, never for data exchange. Behind the scenes, use only [real time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in format of `Continent/Region`.

For data-exchange, use only [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats.

Comment: >To some people that means Central Standard Time, to many more people that means China Standard Time. 

As per java.time.ZoneId java class, CST can only represent central standard time and never any other standard time, let alone China. Not to say that you can get time using CST.